# Override PHP base dependency in composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I try  to install Laravel 5.1 on a host which only has PHP 5.5.6. While I asked the customer to upgrade, this might be not possible/feasible.

So I am getting:

```
- This package requires php >=5.5.9 but your PHP version (5.5.6)
   does not satisfy that requirement.
```

on `composer.phar install`.

Is there a way to do a composer install which ignores this dependency?

I think it should be safe, as there are only bug-fixes from 5.5.6 to 5.5.9.

Comment: The Laravel project unfortunately decided that they declare their 5.1 release compatible to the oldest available PHP version they can test with on TravisCI, which is 5.5.9. On the one hand this is a reasonable choice. On the other hand it is an unnecessary hurdle for people running on older releases of the 5.5 PHP branch, because there are no backwards incompatible changes in PHP 5.5 before 5.5.9 - the code will run. The problem with `--ignore-platform-req` is that it affects ALL packages, you might get packages that only run with PHP 5.6.

Comment: See also: [Reference - Composer error “Your PHP version does not satisfy requirements” after upgrading PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66368196/157957).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The error message indicates a requirement from the main `composer.json`. The version requirement can be just adapted:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5",
```

After changing the version like this I get:

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for classpreloader/classpreloader 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[2.0.0].
    - classpreloader/classpreloader 2.0.0 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.5.6) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.1.17 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.17].
    - laravel/framework v5.1.17 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.5.6) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for laravelcollective/html v5.1.6 -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[v5.1.6].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.6 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.5.6) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - laravel/framework v5.1.17 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.5.6) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - jenssegers/agent v2.1.7 requires illuminate/support ~4.0|~5.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.17].
    - Installation request for jenssegers/agent v2.1.7 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/agent[v2.1.7].
```

Using the following snippet in `composer.json`, a php version can be simulated

```
[...]
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.5.9"
    }
}
```

Doc: https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform

> **platform**
>
> Lets you **fake platform packages** (PHP and extensions) so that you can emulate a production env or define your target platform in the config. Example: {"php": "5.4", "ext-something": "4.0"}.

Don't forget to run a `composer.phar update` after this

Comment: I went through `platform` section but didn't read it carefully. So simple :) I've added doc quote to your answer.

Comment: The simulation of the platform package mentioned here also helps if your base PHP is running a different version to the version which the code is running on. For example, one of my servers running Plesk has a base PHP version of 5.3.x, the code for the virtual site is running on 5.4.x. Without this, a centrally installed composer only picks up on the base version, so can create problems when trying to use a package dependent on a different PHP version

Comment: Is there a way to do this from CLI? Something like `composer install --config platform.php 5.3.3`

Comment: @Starx Why not use `--ignore-platform-reqs` ?

Comment: @Alex, Because I need to specify an older version of PHP in one of the machines.

Comment: @Starx: Yes, `composer config platform.php 5.6`.

Answer (score 162):

You can use `--ignore-platform-reqs` option for composer commands like `install`, `update` etc.

> **--ignore-platform-reqs**: ignore **php**, hhvm, lib-* and ext-* requirements and force the installation even if the local machine does not fulfill these. See also the platform config option.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md

So you can try with

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: Is there also a finer grained method which ignores only the PHP version? Or I even can require 5.5.6 instead of 5.5.9

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing. At least I can't find it.

Comment: Found a way. Was directly there in the docs. But works only for subpackages. See my answer.

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47849825/1883256) as well

Comment: "+1" and More helpful this tutorial: [How to solve Root composer.json requires PHP ^7.3 but your PHP version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement](https://devnote.in/how-to-solve-root-composer-json-requires-php-7-3-but-your-php-version-8-0-0-does-not-satisfy-that-requirement/).

Answer (score 16):

I got the same issue which resolved with following command :

```
composer config platform.php 7.2.22
```

*** you can replace PHP version according to yours.

Comment: Are you sure this helps? If the package asks for a specific PHP version, there might be a good reason not to ignore this

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes defiantly... I've tested this and it works for me that's why I've shared here if it helps anyone else.

Comment: @NicoHaase Also I'm not asking to ignore php version, my issue was there was incorrect php version mentioned in my composer file which I've corrected and composer install worked.

Comment: Thank you. This might be very useful for those on Mac Catalina that updates php right away.

Comment: i think the good way is : `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs `
this commands save my life.. haha :v

Answer (score 9):

Root composer.json requires php ^7.3 but your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.

`composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't use the other answers with the recommended-project `composer --ignore-platform-reqs create-project drupal/recommended-project:8.9.20 project-name` but this answer worked.

Answer (score 3):

Just add these lines in composer.json file

```
  "config": {
    "platform": {
      "php": "5.5.9"
    }
  },
```

Then run command,

```
composer update or install
```

Answer (score 3):

change your php version like

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    .....
},
```

or like

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.3",
    .....
},
```

Answer (score 2):

running a version independent command solves this error 
**composer install --ignore-platform-reqs**

Answer (score 1):

change php version in composer.json

Delete composer.lock

> RUN: composer install

It works for me