# Composer will not install backages when my PHP version doesn't match the requirements

Tags: php, composer-php, php-7

When I upgrade my PHP version to 7.0.2 I have problems with a couple of Composer packages which have requirements that demand version ~5.3. Composer doesn’t want to resolve these packages. I'm quite sure that there is nothing in that package what will break PHP.

Is there a good way to deal with this? Can I somehow force Composer to not look at the requirements and install the packages anyway?

Comment: Duplicate targets: [Reference - Composer error "Your PHP version does not satisfy requirements" after upgrading PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66368196/reference-composer-error-your-php-version-does-not-satisfy-requirements-afte) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/32838881

Answer (score 1):

OK, i found answer in [composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install)

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```