# Composer Update Error "Requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I Just Update My Composer Which Returns with some errors and issues:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

- jeremykenedy/laravel-roles v1.2.0 requires laravel/framework 5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.* -> found 
laravel/framework[v5.3.0-RC1, ..., 5.6.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require 
(^8.0).

- jeremykenedy/laravel-roles v1.3.0 requires laravel/framework 5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.* -> found 
laravel/framework[v5.3.0-RC1, ..., 5.7.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require 
(^8.0).

- jeremykenedy/laravel-roles[v1.4.0, ..., v1.7.0] require laravel/framework 
5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.* -> found laravel/framework[v5.3.0-RC1, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but it 
conflicts with your root composer.json require (^8.0).

- Root composer.json requires jeremykenedy/laravel-roles ^1.2 -> satisfiable by jeremykenedy/laravel- 
roles[v1.2.0, ..., v1.7.0].
```

I Searched on google but failed to solve my issue. Plz, Provide me clear answer So I solve my error.
Thanks, Brother For the Help.

After execution of

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Following Errors Also Occur:

> Class App\Http\Controllers\riderOrders located in L:/Live/cyber-food-
> fiji/app\Http\Controllers\RiderOrders.php does not comply with psr-4
> autoloading standard. Skipping.

> Class "Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\SpatialServiceProvider" not found

> Script @php artisan package: discover handling the post-autoload-dump
> event returned with error code 1

After Execution of
composer update

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> Problem 1

> ```
> - pusher/pusher-php-server[v3.2.0, ..., v3.3.1] require php ^5.4 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
> ```

> ```
> - pusher/pusher-php-server v3.4.0 requires php >=5.4 <7.3 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
> ```

> ```
> - pusher/pusher-php-server v3.4.1 requires php >=5.4 <7.4 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
> ```

> ```
> - Root composer.json requires pusher/pusher-php-server ^3.2 -> satisfiable by pusher/pusher-php-server[v3.2.0, ..., v3.4.1].
> ```

Thanks For Helping me with the last bug.
Plz Also guide in the above errors.
Thanks...

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: when i run PHP artisan serve, PHP artisan, etc...  it gives `Class "Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\SpatialServiceProvider" not found` this error

Comment: Do these answer your question? [How to explain Composer's error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073506/how-to-explain-composers-error-log) and [Reference - Composer error "Your PHP version does not satisfy requirements" after upgrading PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66368196/reference-composer-error-your-php-version-does-not-satisfy-requirements-afte)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

or

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

**Note:**

`--ignore-platform-reqs:` ignore all platform requirements (php, hhvm, lib-* and ext-*) and force the installation even if the local machine does not fulfill these. See also the platform config option.
`--ignore-platform-req:` ignore a specific platform requirement(php, hhvm, lib-* and ext-*) and force the installation even if the local machine does not fulfill it.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I just run this `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` and my composer starts installing without any issue. Thanks.