# laravel/framework 9.x-dev requires php ^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.13) does not satisfy that requirement

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install `league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3` package.. My current laravel version is `5.7.*`

When I try to run `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "^1.0"`

I get lots of issues :(

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

    Problem 1
        - laravel/framework 9.x-dev requires php ^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - Conclusion: don't install fruitcake/laravel-cors v2.0.4
        - Conclusion: don't install fruitcake/laravel-cors v2.0.3
        - Conclusion: don't install fruitcake/laravel-cors v2.0.2
        - Conclusion: don't install fruitcake/laravel-cors v2.0.1
        - Conclusion: don't install fruitcake/laravel-cors v2.0.0
        - Conclusion: don't install fruitcake/laravel-cors v2.0.0-beta3
        - Conclusion: don't install fruitcake/laravel-cors v2.0.0-beta2
        - Conclusion: don't install fruitcake/laravel-cors v2.0.0-beta1
        - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - Installation request for asm89/stack-cors (locked at 1.2.0) -> satisfiable by asm89/stack-cors[1.2.0].
        - Installation request for fruitcake/laravel-cors ^2.0 -> satisfiable by fruitcake/laravel-cors[2.0.x-dev, v2.0.0, v2.0.0-beta1, v2.0.0-beta2, v2.0.0-beta3, v2.0.1, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4].
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - fruitcake/laravel-cors 2.0.x-dev requires illuminate/support ^6|^7|^8|^9 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[6.x-dev, 7.x-dev, 8.x-dev, 9.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.25, v6.18.26, v6.18.27, v6.18.28, v6.18.29, v6.18.3, v6.18.30, v6.18.31, v6.18.32, v6.18.33, v6.18.34, v6.18.35, v6.18.36, v6.18.37, v6.18.38, v6.18.39, v6.18.4, v6.18.40, v6.18.41, v6.18.42, v6.18.43, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.19.0, v6.19.1, v6.2.0, v6.20.0, v6.20.1, v6.20.10, v6.20.11, v6.20.12, v6.20.13, v6.20.14, v6.20.15, v6.20.16, v6.20.17, v6.20.18, v6.20.19, v6.20.2, v6.20.20, v6.20.21, v6.20.22, v6.20.23, v6.20.24, v6.20.25, v6.20.26, v6.20.27, v6.20.28, v6.20.29, v6.20.3, v6.20.30, v6.20.4, v6.20.5, v6.20.6, v6.20.7, v6.20.8, v6.20.9, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.26.0, v7.26.1, v7.27.0, v7.28.0, v7.28.1, v7.28.2, v7.28.3, v7.28.4, v7.29.0, v7.29.1, v7.29.2, v7.29.3, v7.3.0, v7.30.0, v7.30.1, v7.30.2, v7.30.3, v7.30.4, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2, v8.0.0, v8.0.1, v8.0.2, v8.0.3, v8.0.4, v8.1.0, v8.10.0, v8.11.0, v8.11.1, v8.11.2, v8.12.0, v8.12.1, v8.12.2, v8.12.3, v8.13.0, v8.14.0, v8.15.0, v8.16.0, v8.16.1, v8.17.0, v8.17.2, v8.18.0, v8.18.1, v8.19.0, v8.2.0, v8.20.0, v8.20.1, v8.21.0, v8.22.0, v8.22.1, v8.23.1, v8.24.0, v8.25.0, v8.26.0, v8.26.1, v8.27.0, v8.28.0, v8.28.1, v8.29.0, v8.3.0, v8.30.0, v8.30.1, v8.31.0, v8.32.0, v8.32.1, v8.33.0, v8.33.1, v8.34.0, v8.35.0, v8.35.1, v8.36.0, v8.36.1, v8.36.2, v8.37.0, v8.38.0, v8.39.0, v8.4.0, v8.40.0, v8.41.0, v8.42.0, v8.42.1, v8.43.0, v8.44.0, v8.45.0, v8.45.1, v8.46.0, v8.47.0, v8.48.0, v8.48.1, v8.48.2, v8.49.0, v8.49.1, v8.49.2, v8.5.0, v8.50.0, v8.51.0, v8.6.0, v8.7.0, v8.7.1, v8.8.0, v8.9.0], laravel/framework[9.x-dev].
        - don't install illuminate/support 6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.10.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.11.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.12.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.13.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.13.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.14.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.15.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.15.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.16.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.17.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.17.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.38|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.39|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.40|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.42|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.19.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.19.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.20.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support 8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support 9.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.10.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.10.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.10.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.10.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.11.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.12.0|don't 
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.8.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.9.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.9.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v7.9.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.10.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.11.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.11.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.11.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.12.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.12.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.12.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.12.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.13.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.14.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.15.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.16.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.16.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.17.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.17.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.18.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.18.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.19.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.20.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.20.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.21.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.22.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.22.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.23.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.24.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.25.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.26.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.26.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.27.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.28.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.28.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.29.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.30.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.30.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.31.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.32.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.32.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.33.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.33.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.34.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.35.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.35.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.36.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.36.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.36.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.37.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.38.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.39.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.40.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.41.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.42.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.42.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.43.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.44.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.45.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.45.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.46.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.47.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.48.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.48.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.48.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.49.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.49.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.49.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.50.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.51.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - don't install illuminate/support v8.9.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
        - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.7.28, required as 5.7.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.28].


    Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Ok I don't want to upgrade laravel or php at this moment since its a live application and don't have so much time upgrade.

My composer.json file look like this

```
        {
        "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "type": "project",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": [
            "framework",
            "laravel"
        ],
        "license": "MIT",
        "require": {
            "php": "^7.1.3",
            "bogardo/mailgun": "^5.2",
            "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
            "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
            "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
            "intervention/image": "^2.4",
            "kriswallsmith/buzz": "^1.1",
            "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
            "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
            "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^2.1",
            "nwidart/laravel-modules": "^4.0",
            "nyholm/psr7": "^1.3",
            "predis/predis": "^1.1",
            "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.69",
            "symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "^1.2",
            "tillkruss/laravel-phpredis": "^1.1"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
            "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
            "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
            "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
            "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
            "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
        },
        "config": {
            "optimize-autoloader": true,
            "preferred-install": "dist",
            "sort-packages": true
        },
        "extra": {
            "laravel": {
                "dont-discover": []
            }
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "App\\": "app/",
                "Modules\\": "Modules/"
            },
            "classmap": [
                "database/seeds",
                "database/factories"
            ]
        },
        "autoload-dev": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Tests\\": "tests/"
            }
        },
        "minimum-stability": "dev",
        "prefer-stable": true,
        "scripts": {
            "post-autoload-dump": [
                "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
                "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
            ],
            "post-root-package-install": [
                "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd": [
                "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28" is enough for me, pretty sure Laravel is at 8.x now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - Composer error "Your PHP version does not satisfy requirements" after upgrading PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66368196/reference-composer-error-your-php-version-does-not-satisfy-requirements-afte)

Comment: Laravel 8 has a minimum requirement of PHP 8. You have PHP 7.

Comment: can you share your composer.json ? Laravel 9 is still in development and unreleased so you should make sure you're not accidentally including that or other packages that are in development and depend on that

Comment: Need to see your composer.json file. It looks like you are trying to update Laravel itself to Laravel 9 which needs PHP 8.

Comment: Updated question with composer.json file.

Comment: How can we actually install only that package instead looking at all other packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Composer is telling you what is wrong. It wants PHP8 and you offer php7.4, so it doesnt install.

From the comments it also says that laravel 9 is in development. As you're stuggling with this, I dont recommend using that version and go one back, using 8.

What I recommend doing (and what I've been doing lately to a much larger website), is first to run `composer update`. That way, you update all packages in a sem-ver method (so only minor updates). Deploy that to your server.

Than you can use `composer outdated` to see what you can update. Do `composer update package/name -W` (with all dependencies), just one at a time. if you run into a problem, just goto the next one, sometimes after you come back you can still do it.

If you go to [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/) you can search your package and see what the current versions are. Sometimes you can go up a few mayors, sometimes one, sometimes only minor. It's a bit of a puzzle.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions, is there anyways to stay in same version of php and laravel? I don't want laravel 8 or 9. I want to keep 5.7..

Comment: do everything per my answer, but skip the laravel packages as my last paragraph

Comment: I recommend updating though. Security, weird behaviour, all kinds of updates. ANd per my answer, you have a lot of control

Comment: Thank you, this suggestions seems great. I updated and at least this one package is installed and some packages got updated, still I see many packages not updated which I can do one by one later! Make sense

Comment: Out of curiosity: `composer update`  will already update all packages, to the latest compatible version defined in the json. What should `composer package/name -W`  do afterwards?

Comment: That shouldve been an update also. Now you can update one package at a time, going a mayor up :)