# Composer detected issues in your platform. How can I fix this?

Tags: composer-php, laravel-8

Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.4.0".

Comment: What PHP version are you running?

Comment: @Subrata Deb Nath: What prevents you upgrading that platform?

Comment: @hakre that's not necessarily the case, which is why I asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66368196/reference-composer-error-your-php-version-does-not-satisfy-requirements-afte

Comment: @MarshallC: Good thinking! Perhaps theirs thems users have no concept about PHP version as well. Still thought, executing a Composer command might be a category in theirs thems users understanding: Please use `--ignore-platform-reqs` with your Composer command.