# Composer update gives error phpunit/phpunit

Tags: php, composer-php, phpunit, laravel-9

I recently installed php (8.1.7) and composer (2.3.7) and laravel 9;
Now I am getting this error while running the command
`composer update` 
on a laravel project, I searched a lot but couldn't find exact solution, all of them were not discussing the issue of phpunit/phpunit.

The error looks like this:

````
  Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit[6.0.0, ..., 6.5.14] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ~6.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.0.0, ..., 6.5.14].```
````

Comment: Just read! `require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.7) does not satisfy that requirement.`, means you need any version of PHP 7.x instead of PHP 8.1.7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - Composer error "Your PHP version does not satisfy requirements" after upgrading PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66368196/reference-composer-error-your-php-version-does-not-satisfy-requirements-afte)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to upgrade your `phpunit` version to correspond with your `php 8.1.7` (**choose between phpunit version 9 or 8**, according to the [official documentation](https://phpunit.de/supported-versions.html))  or downgrade your php version to works with `phpunit 6.*`.

That's it !