# Installation fails during Composer Update

Tags: laravel, composer-php, dompdf

I get the following error when I want to do a composer update:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

> Problem 1
> - dompdf/dompdf[v0.8.5, ..., v0.8.6] require php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - Root composer.json requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.8.5 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.8.5, v0.8.6].

What can I do?

I try `composer require dompdf/dompdf:^2.1`

and then come this Problem:
[image]

This is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5||^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.0",
        "livewire/livewire": "^1.2",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "rachidlaasri/laravel-installer": "^4.1",
        "spatie/laravel-mix-preload": "^1.1",
        "spatie/laravel-query-builder": "^2.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.7",
        "facade/ignition": "^2.3.6",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel-shift/blueprint": "^1.13",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "platform-check": false
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi",
            "@php artisan ide-helper:generate"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Thank you all for your help

Comment: did you try to update `dompdf/dompdf` to newer version?

Comment: @devnullΨ I am now trying to manually delete from composer and try to install it again.

Comment: use ``"dompdf/dompdf": "^2.0.3",``

Comment: I guess this is related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66368196/reference-composer-error-your-php-version-does-not-satisfy-requirements-afte

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - Composer error "Your PHP version does not satisfy requirements" after upgrading PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66368196/reference-composer-error-your-php-version-does-not-satisfy-requirements-afte)

Comment: I corrected my question and typed what I tried now

Comment: did you update your project according to documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade

Comment: @Michael did you check my answer? any comments?

Answer (score -1):

First of all **there is no dompdf:2.1**

you should change your command:

```
composer require dompdf/dompdf:^2.0.1
```

Even you can use version `2.0.3` which is latest at current time!

Then **delete the `composer.lock` file** in your project root and try again to see if problem goes away.

If not, you should check all other packages versions to support `PHP8.0`

> First, make sure you're at the latest version of Laravel 6, 7 or 8 to get PHP 8 support. Then make sure you're on the very latest version of any first-party package from Laravel like Passport, Cashier, Dusk, etc.

There are also a couple of commonly used dependencies you'll need to update in your composer.json file:

> - PHP to php:^8.0
> - Faker to fakerphp/faker:^1.9.1
> - PHPUnit to phpunit/phpunit:^9.3

> Finally, run composer update to update other packages. Make sure to test your application before updating production. That's it! Enjoy PHP 8!

[Read laravel blog about it](https://blog.laravel.com/laravel-php-8-support)

Comment: Changing the requirement won't resolve the problems about the wrong PHP version being used

Comment: First problem is the version he wants. doesn't exist at all! so you have to change the version to real version!

Comment: Then I said to remove `composer.lock` to update packages for supporting PHP8.0.
read the last line. there is a documentation

Comment: Removing composer.lock should be the last option, as this would also result in other dependencies being upgraded

Comment: Other dependencies are all laravel dependencies! and it's in laravel blog: doing that for adding support for php8