# Unable to migrate in Laravel after adding docker and deploying in Render web hosting service

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I am quite new to using Docker in Laravel and this is where I got the reference: https://mosesejim.hashnode.dev/how-to-host-your-laravel-app-on-render#clsixs2u7000008l7btrb7k4h?t=1707905926914?utm_source=New%20Reply%20Email&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Notification

root/Dockerfile:

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:latest

COPY . .

# Image config
ENV SKIP_COMPOSER 1
ENV WEBROOT /var/www/html/public
ENV PHP_ERRORS_STDERR 1
ENV RUN_SCRIPTS 1
ENV REAL_IP_HEADER 1

# Laravel config
ENV APP_ENV production
ENV APP_DEBUG false
ENV LOG_CHANNEL stderr

# Allow composer to run as root
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

root/.dockerignore:

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
.env
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
```

root/scripts/00-larvel-deploy.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Running composer"
composer global require hirak/prestissimo
composer install --no-dev --working-dir=/var/www/html

echo "generating application key..."
php artisan key:generate --show

echo "Caching config..."
php artisan config:cache

echo "Caching routes..."
php artisan route:cache

echo "Running migrations..."
php artisan migrate --force
```

root/conf/ngnix/ngnix-site.conf:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Running composer"
composer global require hirak/prestissimo
composer install --no-dev --working-dir=/var/www/html

echo "generating application key..."
php artisan key:generate --show

echo "Caching config..."
php artisan config:cache

echo "Caching routes..."
php artisan route:cache

echo "Running migrations..."
php artisan migrate --force
```

My current database setup is pgsql and details about the setup are submitted in an .env file given by the Render Live hosting network.

This is their application log:

```
==> Deploying...
Running composer
Changed current directory to /root/.composer
Cannot use hirak/prestissimo's latest version 0.3.10 as it requires php ^5.3.2 || ^7.0 which is not satisfied by your platform.
Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
In RequireCommand.php line 225:
                                                                               
  No composer.json present in the current directory (./composer.json), this m  
  ay be the cause of the following exception.                                  
                                                                               
In PackageDiscoveryTrait.php line 317:
                                                                               
  Package hirak/prestissimo has requirements incompatible with your PHP versi  
  on, PHP extensions and Composer version:                                     
    - hirak/prestissimo 0.3.10 requires php ^5.3.2 || ^7.0 which does not mat  
  ch your installed version 8.2.7.                                             
    - hirak/prestissimo 0.3.10 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0.0 which does  
   not match your installed version 2.3.0.                                     
                                                                               
require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [<packages>...]
Installing dependencies from lock file
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Package operations: 74 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading doctrine/inflector (2.0.9)
  - Downloading doctrine/lexer (3.0.1)
  - Downloading symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.29.0)
  - Downloading webmozart/assert (1.11.0)
  - Downloading dragonmantank/cron-expression (v3.3.3)
  - Downloading symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.29.0)
  - Downloading symfony/polyfill-php83 (v1.29.0)
  - Downloading symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.29.0)
  - Downloading symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.4.0)
  - Downloading symfony/http-foundation (v6.4.3)
  - Downloading fruitcake/php-cors (v1.3.0)
  - Downloading psr/http-message (2.0)
  - Downloading psr/http-client (1.0.3)
  - Downloading ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3)
  - Downloading psr/http-factory (1.0.2)
  - Downloading guzzlehttp/psr7 (2.6.2)
  - Downloading guzzlehttp/promises (2.0.2)
  - Downloading guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.8.1)
  - Downloading guzzlehttp/uri-template (v1.0.3)
  - Downloading symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.29.0)
  - Downloading symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.29.0)
  - Downloading symfony/string (v6.4.3)
  - Downloading psr/container (2.0.2)
  - Downloading symfony/service-contracts (v3.4.1)
  - Downloading symfony/console (v6.4.3)
  - Downloading voku/portable-ascii (2.0.1)
  - Downloading phpoption/phpoption (1.9.2)
  - Downloading graham-campbell/result-type (v1.1.2)
  - Downloading vlucas/phpdotenv (v5.6.0)
  - Downloading symfony/css-selector (v6.4.3)
  - Downloading tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (v2.2.7)
  - Downloading symfony/var-dumper (v6.4.3)
  - Downloading symfony/polyfill-uuid (v1.29.0)
  - Downloading symfony/uid (v6.4.3)
  - Downloading symfony/routing (v6.4.3)
  - Downloading symfony/process (v6.4.3)
  - Downloading symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.29.0)
  - Downloading symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.29.0)
  - Downloading symfony/mime (v6.4.3)
  - Downloading psr/event-dispatcher (1.0.0)
  - Downloading symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v3.4.0)
  - Downloading symfony/event-dispatcher (v6.4.3)
  - Downloading psr/log (3.0.0)
  - Downloading egulias/email-validator (4.0.2)
  - Downloading symfony/mailer (v6.4.3)
  - Downloading symfony/error-handler (v6.4.3)
  - Downloading symfony/http-kernel (v6.4.3)
  - Downloading symfony/finder (v6.4.0)
  - Downloading ramsey/collection (2.0.0)
  - Downloading brick/math (0.11.0)
  - Downloading ramsey/uuid (4.7.5)
  - Downloading psr/simple-cache (3.0.0)
  - Downloading nunomaduro/termwind (v1.15.1)
  - Downloading symfony/translation-contracts (v3.4.1)
  - Downloading symfony/translation (v6.4.3)
  - Downloading psr/clock (1.0.0)
  - Downloading carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types (2.1.0)
  - Downloading nesbot/carbon (2.72.3)
  - Downloading monolog/monolog (3.5.0)
  - Downloading league/mime-type-detection (1.15.0)
  - Downloading league/flysystem (3.24.0)
  - Downloading league/flysystem-local (3.23.1)
  - Downloading nette/utils (v4.0.4)
  - Downloading nette/schema (v1.3.0)
  - Downloading dflydev/dot-access-data (v3.0.2)
  - Downloading league/config (v1.2.0)
  - Downloading league/commonmark (2.4.2)
  - Downloading laravel/serializable-closure (v1.3.3)
  - Downloading laravel/prompts (v0.1.15)
  - Downloading laravel/framework (v10.43.0)
  - Downloading laravel/sanctum (v3.3.3)
  - Downloading nikic/php-parser (v5.0.0)
  - Downloading psy/psysh (v0.12.0)
  - Downloading laravel/tinker (v2.9.0)
  0/74 [>---------------------------]   0%
 12/74 [====>-----------------------]  16%
 23/74 [========>-------------------]  31%
 32/74 [============>---------------]  43%
 43/74 [================>-----------]  58%
 51/74 [===================>--------]  68%
 59/74 [======================>-----]  79%
 64/74 [========================>---]  86%
 72/74 [===========================>]  97%
 74/74 [============================] 100%
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (2.0.9): Extracting archive
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (3.0.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.29.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing webmozart/assert (1.11.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing dragonmantank/cron-expression (v3.3.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.29.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php83 (v1.29.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.29.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.4.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v6.4.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing fruitcake/php-cors (v1.3.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/http-message (2.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/http-client (1.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/http-factory (1.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (2.6.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (2.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.8.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing guzzlehttp/uri-template (v1.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.29.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.29.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/string (v6.4.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/container (2.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/service-contracts (v3.4.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/console (v6.4.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing voku/portable-ascii (2.0.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpoption/phpoption (1.9.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing graham-campbell/result-type (v1.1.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v5.6.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v6.4.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (v2.2.7): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v6.4.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-uuid (v1.29.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/uid (v6.4.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/routing (v6.4.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/process (v6.4.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.29.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.29.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/mime (v6.4.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/event-dispatcher (1.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v3.4.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v6.4.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/log (3.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing egulias/email-validator (4.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/mailer (v6.4.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/error-handler (v6.4.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v6.4.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/finder (v6.4.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing ramsey/collection (2.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing brick/math (0.11.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing ramsey/uuid (4.7.5): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/simple-cache (3.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing nunomaduro/termwind (v1.15.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/translation-contracts (v3.4.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/translation (v6.4.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/clock (1.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types (2.1.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing nesbot/carbon (2.72.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing monolog/monolog (3.5.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing league/mime-type-detection (1.15.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing league/flysystem (3.24.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing league/flysystem-local (3.23.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing nette/utils (v4.0.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing nette/schema (v1.3.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing dflydev/dot-access-data (v3.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing league/config (v1.2.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing league/commonmark (2.4.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing laravel/serializable-closure (v1.3.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing laravel/prompts (v0.1.15): Extracting archive
  - Installing laravel/framework (v10.43.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing laravel/sanctum (v3.3.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing nikic/php-parser (v5.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing psy/psysh (v0.12.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing laravel/tinker (v2.9.0): Extracting archive
  0/74 [>---------------------------]   0%
 10/74 [===>------------------------]  13%
 19/74 [=======>--------------------]  25%
 28/74 [==========>-----------------]  37%
 30/74 [===========>----------------]  40%
 38/74 [==============>-------------]  51%
 49/74 [==================>---------]  66%
 54/74 [====================>-------]  72%
 59/74 [======================>-----]  79%
 63/74 [=======================>----]  85%
 68/74 [=========================>--]  91%
 73/74 [===========================>]  98%
 74/74 [============================] 100%
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
   INFO  Discovering packages.  
  laravel/sanctum ....................................................... DONE
  laravel/tinker ........................................................ DONE
  nesbot/carbon ......................................................... DONE
  nunomaduro/termwind ................................................... DONE
53 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
generating application key...
base64:R0IC+qdnB13A0CyJ4nQci1ZgkzVr/bT85sOIhfCtx/4=
Caching config...
   INFO  Configuration cached successfully.  
Caching routes...
   INFO  Routes cached successfully.  
Running migrations...
   INFO  Nothing to migrate.  
2024-02-16 20:40:35,629 WARN No file matches via include "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf"
2024-02-16 20:40:35,629 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded
2024-02-16 20:40:35,655 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2024-02-16 20:40:35,655 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2024-02-16 20:40:35,655 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2024-02-16 20:40:36,658 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 240
2024-02-16 20:40:36,660 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 241
2024/02/16 20:40:36 [notice] 241#241: using the "epoll" event method
2024/02/16 20:40:36 [notice] 241#241: nginx/1.24.0
2024/02/16 20:40:36 [notice] 241#241: OS: Linux 5.15.0-1052-aws
2024/02/16 20:40:36 [notice] 241#241: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2024/02/16 20:40:36 [notice] 241#241: start worker processes
2024/02/16 20:40:36 [notice] 241#241: start worker process 242
2024/02/16 20:40:36 [notice] 241#241: start worker process 243
2024/02/16 20:40:36 [notice] 241#241: start worker process 244
2024/02/16 20:40:36 [notice] 241#241: start worker process 245
2024/02/16 20:40:36 [notice] 241#241: start worker process 246
2024/02/16 20:40:36 [notice] 241#241: start worker process 247
2024/02/16 20:40:36 [notice] 241#241: start worker process 248
2024/02/16 20:40:36 [notice] 241#241: start worker process 249
[16-Feb-2024 20:40:37] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 240
[16-Feb-2024 20:40:37] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
2024/02/16 20:40:37 [info] 243#243: *1 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 10.219.25.104, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2024/02/16 20:40:37 [info] 242#242: *2 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 10.219.25.104, server: 0.0.0.0:80
Your service is live 
2024-02-16 20:40:38,549 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2024-02-16 20:40:38,549 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Feb/2024:20:40:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3749 "-" "Go-http-client/2.0"
2024/02/16 20:40:42 [info] 245#245: *5 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 10.219.25.104, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2024/02/16 20:40:47 [info] 246#246: *6 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 10.219.25.104, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2024/02/16 20:40:52 [info] 247#247: *7 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 10.219.25.104, server: 0.0.0.0:80
```

I do understand that "hirak/prestissimo" is causing the serious issue in here and I really have little knowledge about how I can manage in this situation.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory, you are using a package that requires a PHP version that you do not use, the `hirak/prestissimo` is mostly dead, and according to [this comment](https://github.com/hirak/prestissimo/issues/246#issuecomment-821940604) you do not need the project anymore as you are using composer 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - Composer error "Your PHP version does not satisfy requirements" after upgrading PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66368196/reference-composer-error-your-php-version-does-not-satisfy-requirements-afte)

Comment: I ran composer install --ignore-platform-req=php and again with composer install --ignore-platform-reqs, in both the cases, I am seeing this error now with a warning: "error
  - Installing symfony/error-handler (v6.4.3): Extracting archive"

with constant errors of:

2024-02-18 15:51:14,712 WARN No file matches via include "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf"  and critical
2024-02-18 15:51:14,789 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking

and I cannot still migrate