# Integrating content in Symfony3 with google maps

Tags: google-maps, symfony

I am trying to use this bundle:
https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/installation.md
With this command:

```
composer require egeloen / google-map-bundle
```

Show me this error:

```
> Problem 1
>     - Conclusion: don't install egeloen/google-map-bundle 2.2.1
>     - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.3.10
>     - Installation request for egeloen/google-map-bundle ^2.2 -> satisfiable by egeloen/google-map-bundle[2.2.0, 2.2.1].
>     - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
```

How can I fix it or know another bundle that works for symfony3?

Comment: Stable version is for Symfony 2 only. You can try to install `master` branch: `composer require egeloen/google-map-bundle:dev-master`

Comment: This is the new error with this command: Problem 1
    - Installation request for egeloen/google-map-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by egeloen/google-map-bundle[dev-master].
    - egeloen/google-map-bundle dev-master requires php ^5.6|^7.0 -> ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in the site of author of Bundle:
https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/issues/175#issuecomment-244535511

This is code in the file composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "egeloen/google-map": "^2.0@dev",
        "egeloen/google-map-bundle": "^3.0@dev"
    }
}
```

And is necessary this code:

```
$ composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

The solution for this part in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32839015/2400373

Regards