# Change Laravel Homestead v7.0.1 with php 7.2 to php 7.1

Tags: laravel, homestead

What are the steps to downgrade the PHP version to 7.1 and make it default on the latest Homestead 7, Homestead 7 comes with PHP version 7.2 as default.

There are several dev sites on my homestead I want everything to run on 7.1
by default, if I need 7.2 then I will use the following in my homestead yaml

```
sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/homestead/public
      php: "7.2"
```

Comment: Seems duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/53641979/1845602

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think I have a better solution, to switch the php version in Homestead (I am using version 8 currently) running following lines of code switches the default php version.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.1
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.1
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.1
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.1
```

Above line will switch the php version from any version to version 7.1 (Homestead 8 comes with php 7.3 by default).

Do remember to reload web-server (apache or nginx) after making this change.

---

> **July 2020 UPDATE:** In newer versions of homestead to change php version there are aliases like `php71` `php72` `php73` `php74` etc. to easily
> swith between versions

Comment: We are talking about changing the default php version in homestead, In my Original post I already mentioned about changing the php version for each site. Thus to change the `default version` in Homestead, above is the solution.

Comment: Above solution can also be used to switch between any version of available php 
 higher or lower versions on homestead.

Answer (score 43):

You can simply run `sudo update-alternatives --config php` and choose from the list like this:

[image]

You should then change the defaults for `phar`, `phar.phar`, `phpize`, `php-config` the same way you did for `php`

Comment: Nice, This is more interactive approach in switching php version. I guess we can similarly change `phar`, `phpize` and `php-config` interactively.

Answer (score 14):

You shouldn't use older versions of Homestead if you just want to use a different version of PHP.

You can set each site to use PHP 7.1, that won't hurt anything. You can change the CLI version by running `php71` from the command line.

Comment: In an absolute last resort you can use https://laravel-news.com/using-older-versions-of-homestead but I would no longer recommend this because it was written before Homestead supported multiple PHP versions.

Comment: So looks like easiest way now is to use `php: "7.1"` tag in yaml file.

Comment: Yes, and don't forget to run your jobs using `php7.1` like this: `$ php7.1 artisan queue:listen ...`

Comment: As time progress, the new thing is Homestead supports multiple php version. And with experience in using the accepted solution, I see no issue switching php versions to older as per need.

Answer (score 1):

As a slightly simpler alternative to `update-alternatives --config php` you can enter the PHP version you want on the command line with a syntax of `php71` where `7` is the major version and `1` the minor version.

For example to switch to PHP 7.1 from another version simply type `php71`.

```
vagrant@local:~/code$ php71
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php7.1 to provide /usr/bin/php (php) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php-config7.1 to provide /usr/bin/php-config (php-config) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/phpize7.1 to provide /usr/bin/phpize (phpize) in manual mode
```

Comment: Right, BTW I did mention this in my answer, Thanks for adding an explanation.