# How to change on Vagrant from PHP 7.2 to PHP 7.3?

Tags: php, laravel

I try to install Laravel 8 to vagrant. The install process works without problem. But the homepage shows the following error:

```
Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.0". You are running 7.2.34-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1. in /home/vagrant/code/7time/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24
```

When I check the version, it shows 7.3

```
vagrant@homestead:~/code$ php -version
PHP 7.3.24-3+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 31 2020 16:59:59) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.24, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.24-3+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

I tried these things:

- I searched on Google for solution
- I reinstalled PHP
- I tried to install Laravel via Laravel installer and via Composer

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Difference CLI / PHP-FPM

$ `php -version` gives the PHP CLI version, not the PHP-FPM version.

$ `service php7.x-fpm status` gives the php-fpm status/version.

### CLI:

$ `php artisan serve` , Runs the application through your cli.

### Homestead ( Vagrant box ):

Homestead ( Vagrant box ) is using NGINX by default.  This means that the application will use PHP-FPM.

---

**Duplicate of:**

[Change Laravel Homestead v7.0.1 with php 7.2 to php 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849825/change-laravel-homestead-v7-0-1-with-php-7-2-to-php-7-1)

[How to roll back PHP version in Vagrant and Homestead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641931/how-to-roll-back-php-version-in-vagrant-and-homestead/53641979#53641979)