# How to use php 8 in laravel homested

Tags: php, laravel, homestead, php-8

I just update laravel homestead to latest version `v10.17.0`. Also I update virtual box and vagrant. Related to laravel homestead documentation php 8 should be supported but I wasn't able to setup.

PHP 7.4 is still default version but that is not a problem because I want to use version 8 only for one project and I set `php: '8.0'` in `Homestead.yaml` for specific site but there is no impact at all.
I also see there is a [function](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/pull/1553) for switching to version 8 in vagrant but I get `command not found`.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Laravel Homestead v7.0.1 with php 7.2 to php 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849825/change-laravel-homestead-v7-0-1-with-php-7-2-to-php-7-1)

Comment: no, I also try that but if you see update from July 2020 in newer version you have this function but for php80 that is not working. `command not found`

Comment: I'm also having this issue. I started a new laravel project on a fresh homestead box and getting all kinds of errors when trying to run php artisan. Shows a ton of deprecated methods and exceptions.

Comment: I didn't find any solution, still

Comment: I ended up rolling back to php 7.4 with the help of Adam P. 's link above. Seems like php 8 breaks several things. I also made sure I started on a fresh laravel 8 project this time.