# Getting an PHP Deprecated error : ReflectionParameter::getClass()

Tags: php, laravel

i am using php 7.4.0. when i run my application im getting an error. any suggestion?

Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass()

Comment: Are you sure is not PHP 8?

Comment: Seems like same to this question.

Comment: ah im using homestead and these are my config : "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "laravel/homestead": "^12.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"

Comment: try phpinfo() for see the real php version please.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini  thanks, it stated im using php 8.0 but when i check the version on the cli it is 7.4.0 any suggestions how to downgrade ? btw im using homestead

Comment: try to see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849825/change-laravel-homestead-v7-0-1-with-php-7-2-to-php-7-1), but i suggest you to improve your code for php8

Comment: im already working on an existing app, btw i modified the homestead.yaml and didnt work out :( ,,, any other way to set the php version ?

Comment: you need to change it on server.