# Homestead refuses to use specific PHP version (7.1 instead of 8.0)

Tags: laravel, homestead

**The Short Version**

Laravel application on Homestead is using PHP 8.x as seen in phpinfo(), yet `php -v` is stating the server is using 7.1 (which is what I want). How is this possible? How do I tell the Laravel application to use 7.1 not 8.x?

**The Long Version**

I have an older Laravel application (5.8) that I need to upgrade to 8.0. I may be using Shift to do this but I have never done an upgrade manually so I thought I should do that at least once.

So I upgraded Homestead to current (12.x), and everything continued to run fine.

Then I tried to upgrade my PHP version from 7.1 to 8.0 using `sudo update-alternatives --config php` and chose PHP. Then I verified with `php -v` that it switched to that version. As expected, I began getting deprecation errors in browser. Knowing I would have to spend some time resolving those I switched back to 7.1... but the errors remained!

I restarted PHP, I restarted the server, I reloaded and reprovisioned the server, I destroyed and reprovisioned the server and absolutely nothing is resolving this issue. I even specified `php: "7.1"` in the Homestead.yaml file and re-provisioned to no avail.

At this point it seems that the upgrading of Homestead itself is somehow telling PHP to ignore the version I'm specifying it to use. So I know I could downgrade, I suppose, but that isn't really a solution but a band aid. And I'm not certain that will actually work either.

I've tried the Answers in this StackOverflows [Change Laravel Homestead v7.0.1 with php 7.2 to php 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849825/change-laravel-homestead-v7-0-1-with-php-7-2-to-php-7-1) including php71.

OS: Windows 10
Homestead: 12.x

This person has an identical problem and resolved it with Docker somehow but I don't understand how to translate that to Homestead.

Answer (score 2):

There is PHP-CLI and PHP-web. PHP-CLI version is what is reported when using `php -v` but PHP-CLI is what NGinx is using, hence getting 8.0 when using `phpinfo()` in `~/public/index.php`

To resolve the issue I manually updated `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite` and edited line below `location` where it says `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;` to say `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;` and then I restarted PHP with `sudo systemctl restart nginx`.