# while installing laravel getting an error guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.0.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (8.0.7) does not satisfy that requirement

Tags: laravel, guzzle

```
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.0.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (8.0.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.0.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (8.0.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.0.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (8.0.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/guzzle (locked at 7.0.1) -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.0.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override PHP base dependency in composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838881/override-php-base-dependency-in-composer)

Comment: Which version of php are you using?
Try:
composer clearcache 
composer selfupdate

Answer (score 0):

Use the option `--with-all-dependencies (-W)`

```
composer require intervention/image -W
```

This is to allow upgrades, downgrades, and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.